# ソフトウエアキーボードの「次へ」を消したい

Tags: javascript, monaca

`input type="number"` でテンキーボードが表示されますが、右下の「次へ」を押すと画面が乱れてしまいます。

実機は Xperia z3 compact ですが、Xperia のスマホでは「次へ」ではなく「＞」と表示されていて押してもなにも反応しません。

キーコードがわかれば無視できるかと思ったのですが `window.event.keyCode` ではキーコードが取得できず画面が乱れてしまいます。（通常の数字は取得できています。）

このキーを表示しないあるいは押されても無視するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Comment: 画面が乱れるというのは正確ではありませんでした。カルーセルの1ページ目にinputタグがありますが、「次へ」を押すと2ページ目に移動して1ページ目には戻ることが出来なくなります。ページを移動するようなコードはありません。

Comment: 結局、ons-modalでテンキーを作りました。